troubleshooting Azure API Management URI rewrite
Arriving URL format https://my-apim.azure-api.net/product/service1/v3/service1/operation. Client library prefix second "service1" to the URL, my base URL: "https://my-apim.azure-api.net/product/service1/" , version - v3, operation - "/operation". Because of second "service1" in the URL APIM can't find matching API operation.
I have added rewrite-uri to the inbound Policies to remove second "service1", so it can match operation:
<rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.ToString().Replace("service1/operation", "operation"))" copy-unmatched-params="true" />

It didn't help.
I did try to debug/trace it. It looks like matching to operation comes before rewrite-uri policy and it will always return 404. In the trace API and version are matched correct, but not operation.
Snippet from trace output:
{
                "source": "api-inspector",
                "timestamp": "2024-09-05T07:12:38.9153327Z",
                "elapsed": "00:00:00.0003329",
                "data": {
                    "configuration": {
                        "api": {
                            "from": "/product/service1",
                            "to": null,
                            "version": "v3",
                            "revision": "1"
                        },
                        "operation": "-",
                        "user": "-",
                        "product": {
                            "id": "product"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

If operation is matched, the uri-write works as expected.
How can I modify URI before it is matched to API and operation?
EDIT:
backend URL format: https://server1.contoso.com/service1/

Can you share the backend URL format? I believe the operation is not hitting backend

Generally, APIM Base URL format looks like https://{apimInstanceName}.azure-api.net.  So, If you will create a new API by providing the details as given below then the endpoint would be in the required format https://{apimInstanceName}.azure-api.net/product/service1/v3/operation when created.

Then, you need to add an operation by providing URL template value as /operation to get the desired endpoint format.

While testing, I am not getting 404 error and its correctly hitting the backend URL.

I have noticed, to attribute in api-inspector is null in your case. It will be null if you haven't configured backend URL, even I have tried it by deleting the backend URL.


It works as you shown. My problem is that incoming request is not in format "product/service1/v3/operation", but "product/service1/v3/extratext/operation". My goal is to remove URL part "/extratext" with rewrite-uri before matching to operation. It seems rewrite-uri Policy is not applied before matching to operation.

@Robert What do you mean by incoming request? Are you invoking it externally or how?

Its client API request generated by python module which adds this "extratext". Unfortunately I cannot change python module behavior, so I try to manipulate it in API gateway, so it matches correct operation.

@Robert In that case, you can add that extratext in the operation too. I believe you can't use any policy here because its failing to hit the endpoint itself

The policy is not going to work here because operation is not identified from URL. The suggestion from Microsoft support was to use header or query parameter based versioning. Then version is no longer in URL. Not the best solution, but the only I can work with.
